# Angular: Update service and share data between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, promise, factory

I'm using a service to grab some data from an API:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.factory('myService', function($q, $timeout) {
    var getMessages = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function() {
            deferred.resolve('Hello world!');
        }, 2000);

        return deferred.promise;
    };

  return {
    getMessages: getMessages
  };

});
```

And I use these data in multiple controllers.

```
function ControllerA($scope, myService) {
    $scope.message = myService.getMessages();
    $scope.updateMessage = function(){
        $scope.message = 'Hello Max';        
    };
}

function ControllerB($scope, myService) {
    $scope.message = myService.getMessages();
    $scope.$watch('message', function(){
       // 'Hello Max'
    }, true);
}
```

I would like to update the data in every controller, but when I change the $scope.message in the ControllerA, it doesn't fire a change in the ControllerB.

**EDIT:** The thing is that I would like to avoid using "$broadcast" and "$on".

Any ideas?

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Victa/McLQD/

Answer (score 8):

You can use `$broadcast` to broadcast an event to the `rootScope` and use `$on` to define listener to listen to this specific event.

```
function ControllerA($scope, myService, $rootScope) {
    $scope.message = myService.getMessages();
    $scope.updateMessage = function () {
        $scope.message = 'Hello Max';

        $rootScope.$broadcast("HelloEvent", {
            msg: $scope.message
        });
    };
}

function ControllerB($scope, myService, $rootScope) {
    $scope.message = myService.getMessages();

    $rootScope.$on("HelloEvent", function (event, message) {
        $scope.message = message.msg;
    });
}
```

**Updated:**

I got the above solution just before you updated your question. If you don't want to use $broadcast or $on, you can share the object via `$rootScop`e like this

```
function ControllerA($scope, myService, $rootScope) {
    $scope.message = myService.getMessages();
    $scope.updateMessage = function () {
        $scope.message = 'Hello Max';
        $rootScope.message = 'Hello Max';
    };
}

function ControllerB($scope, myService, $timeout, $rootScope) {
    $scope.message = myService.getMessages();

    $rootScope.$watch('message', function (oldV, newV) {
        if(oldV === undefined && oldV === newV) return;
        $scope.message = $rootScope.message;
    });
}
```

<kbd>**[Demo using broadcast](http://jsfiddle.net/RDdPx/)**</kbd>
<kbd>**[Demo without using broadcast](http://jsfiddle.net/3dGL3/)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the thing is that I would like to avoid using "$broadcast" and "$on".