# Update dashboard from the dropdown choice in a angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, service, dashboard

I have an angularjs application that have a dashboard that is built from services. These Services are called passing a parameter like a user ID.

In this dashboard we have a dropdown that offer a user change, and when this happens i have to update all my services and dashboard.

How can i do that? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to write code. Check out [ask] and [mcve] then come back and edit your question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

See this https://www.codementor.io/angularjs/tutorial/create-dropdown-control and and then register a listener to the 'user change' field like in this thread [Angular: Update service and share data between controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195498/angular-update-service-and-share-data-between-controllers)

You can also use `$scope.$watch()` ([How do I use $scope.$watch and $scope.$apply in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply-in-angularjs), http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)

In general use the standard angular controller for this. In the following the text in the input-fields *First Name* and *Last Name* is set to *John Doe*

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
</script>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp

In the controller for the dropdown menu, parse the new user id when 'user change' is clicked and execute the changes in dashboard you want (change name in textfield, update services (see link above),...) depending on the new user id.

Comment: Thanks ralf htp! I will try